# how to delete the contents of a folder in obj c

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, directory, nsfilemanager

i used the following method to delete all the contents of the folder

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray* arrFilePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * strFilePath = [arrFilePath objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *directory = [strFilePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Electronic_Instrumentation-Sapna_publications"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    for (NSString *file in [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:&error]) 
    {
        directory = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
        BOOL success = [fm removeItemAtPath:directory error:&error];
        file = nil;
        if (!success || error) 
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to remove files");
        }
    }
```

but its deleting only first file in the directory

say i have 3 files in the dorectory file1.txt, file2.txt,file3.txt

when i call this method it ill delete only file1.txt but not other files , again if i call that method it ill delete file2.txt but not file3.txt

how can i fix this,,??

is there any way to delete a directory ??  thanx in advance

Comment: add these files u want delete in nsarray and add looping one by one all object specified in array will be deleted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're changing `directory` the first time you go through your loop. Thereafter, you're using an invalid path. First time through the loop, `directory` has something like:

```
/path/to/the/file1.txt
```

The next time through the loop, you append the next file name, so `directory` becomes:

```
/path/to/the/file1.txt/file2.txt
```

That obviously won't work.

The best way to *find* a problem like this is to step through the code in the debugger, watching the relevant variables as you go.

The right way to *fix* this problem, now that you know what it is, is to stop modifying `directory`. You could use a temporary variable, like this:

```
for (NSString *file in [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:&error]) 
{
    NSString *path = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
    BOOL success = [fm removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];
```

Or you could just use the result of `-stringByAppendingPathComponent:` as the argument to `-removeItemAtPath:error:`, like this:

```
for (NSString *file in [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:&error]) 
{
    BOOL success = [fm removeItemAtPath:[directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file]
                                  error:&error];
```

> **is there any way to delete a directory ??**

You could check the docs for `-removeItemAtPath:error:`. I'll save you a trip:

> A path string indicating the file or directory to remove. If the path
>   specifies a directory, the contents of that directory are recursively
>   removed.

So yes, there is an easy way to delete a directory. Just specify the directory in the `path` argument to `-removeItemAtPath:error:`.